# Why is my function returning 1 and not the variable value?

Tags: c, initialization, return-value, declaration, function-declaration

I am new to C and learning it for my University course. I am learning about functions and have to create a function that doesn't have any `printf` or `scanf` in it, just a function that calculates how many days are in a week.

```
int main(days)
{

    int weeks;

    printf("\nPlease enter a number of weeks: ");
    scanf("%i", &weeks);

    weekstodays(weeks);

    printf("\nThere are %i days in %i weeks.\n", days, weeks);
    return 0;
}
int weekstodays(weeks){

    int days;

    days = weeks * 7;
    printf("%i", days);

    return(days);

}
```

Whenever I build and run this, the `main` function outputs 1 day, but the `weekstodays` function outputs the desired result. (The `printf` in the `weekstodays` function is just to see the value of `days`)
Does anyone know why the `weekstodays` function is not returning the `day` variable correctly?

Comment: `days` in `main()` and `days` in `weekstodays()` are different variables.

Comment: `int main(days)` ????

Comment: Suggestion: turn on and mind the maximum warnings your compiler can output.

Comment: `int main(days)` ought to cause at least a compiler warning.  The only reason any compiler accepts that is to conform with decades old bad practice. Probably, the compiler is treating that as equivalent to `int main(int days)` (so the behavior is actually undefined) and days is just the number of arguments passed to the program.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in valid C code that compiles with a working C compiler. This code does not. https://godbolt.org/z/eba3Kbe7K

Comment: Also check out [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the returned value of the function in this statement

```
weekstodays(weeks);
```

Write

```
int days = weekstodays(weeks);
```

Pay attention to that the function declaration is incorrect

```
int weekstodays(weeks){
```

Write

```
int weekstodays(int weeks){
```

Also place one more function declaration before main.

Pay attention to that also the declaration of main is incorrect

```
int main(days)
```

According to the C Standard the function shall be declared either like

```
int main( void )
```

or

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
```

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Das ist fantastisch!

Comment: @Darth-CodeX I do not argue.